# How do view controllers in tabbar controller communicate -iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, communication

In my app I need to communicate two viewcontrollers  which are inside a tabbarcontroller.

That is the value of an object in viewcontroller in first tab index can be changed from viewcontroller in second  tabindex.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Also, you can use your delegate to expose the properties, variables and objects, which can be changed by other objects. You can also share the instances of the two view controllers in the delegate, and access the objects/proeperties from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of stuff I usually use NSNotifications. I've answered a similar question here: [passing data objects between view-controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259982/passing-data-objects-moc-between-viewcontrollers-best-practice/8260387#8260387)