# How can i define a global variable Class in Swift

Tags: class, swift, variables, global

I am new to swift, a need to define a global variable class to be used in every controller class.

Thanks.

Comment: You want just your controller classes to use your 'global variable class' or you want all controller classes, including UIViewController, etc, to use your 'global variable class'?

Comment: can you give me an example.

Comment: all controller classes

Comment: I created a development blog post about this very subject, and then wrote an SO question/answer discussing it. See the SO article at this link: [**How do you share data between view controllers and other objects in Swift?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734954/how-do-you-share-data-between-view-controllers-and-other-objects-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can us something like this:

```
class Favorites {
var favoritesArray:Array <AnyObject>

init(favoritesArray:Array <AnyObject>) {
    self.favoritesArray = favoritesArray
    }
}
```

and declare it as :

```
var favoritesInstance = Favorites(favoritesArray:["Harpers_Bazaar_Ch_03_15_0000.jpg"])
```

and call it from anywhere as :

```
let x = favoritesInstance.favoritesArray
```