# Calling upon the previous view controller in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am trying to call upon the root controller and I don't know the code to call upon it.  I'm using a conditional and which will check what the previous view controller was, and a block of code will run depending on what it was.  Here is my code:

SecondViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad ( ) {
     super.viewDidLoad ( )

     let previousController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier ("firstViewController") as? FirstViewController

     //HELP IN LINE BELOW
     //if root view controller == previousController {
              //run some code
     //}
}
```

Comment: `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` will create each time a new view controller. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you share data between view controllers and other objects in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734954/how-do-you-share-data-between-view-controllers-and-other-objects-in-swift)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
let stack = self.navigationController.viewControllers
if (stack.count > 1) {
    let previousController = stack[stack.count-2]
}
```

Or if you don't have a navigation controller

```
let previousController = self.presentingViewController
```

Also, just to be clear, the root view controller will be the first view controller in the stack, i.e:

```
self.navigationController.viewControllers.firstObject
```

or

```
var previousController : UIViewController = self
var rootController : UIViewController?
do {
    var rootViewController = previousController
    var previousController = rootViewController.presentingViewController
} while (previousController != nil)
```