# Passing the Object from one ViewController to another

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "shoesDetails" {
        let indexPath = self.table.indexPathForSelectedRow()    
        let shoesCon:ShoesTableControler = segue.destinationViewController as! ShoesTableControler
        let shoesCategories:RepoSitory = arrofRepository[indexPath!.row]       
        shoesCon.object = shoesCategories
    }
 }

class ShoesTableControler: UIViewController {
    var object = [ProductShoes]()
}

class ProductShoes {
    var product_id : String
    var product_name : String

    init(json :NSDictionary) {
        self.product_id = json["product_id"] as! String
        self.product_name = json["product_name"] as! String
    } 
    class RepoSitory {
var name : String
var ids : String

init(json :NSDictionary) {
   self.name = json["category_name"] as! String
   self.ids = json["id"] as! String



}
```

}

I have 3 classes in firstViewController. We show the data it's done. After that, when user click on specific cell, then show the data. Now I have created the ShoesTableController and in ShoesTableController we create the Product Class obj. I want to access this. The problem is in this line in Objective C. I am doing this and it is working perfect but in swift it does  know what happened:

```
 shoesCon.object = shoesCategories
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you share data between view controllers and other objects in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734954/how-do-you-share-data-between-view-controllers-and-other-objects-in-swift)

Comment: i see this but my problem is different bro

Comment: Then as a start, you need to explain what's not working.  What's happening?  Is there a compile time error?  Is it crashing?  Is it launching missiles?  What's happening that's different from your expectations?

Comment: bro sorry i think so you mind it  error is this "Cannot Assign a value of type Class to a value of type ProductShoes"

Comment: Cannot Assign a value of type RepoSitory to a value of type ProductShoes

Comment: According to the code you have posted, `shoesCategories` is of type `RepoSitory`. Whereas `shoesCon.object` is defined as an array of `ProductShoes`. That is why you are unable to assign the value of `shoesCategories` to the object.

Comment: but in Objective C i am doing this and properly work it than how we are doing in swift?

Answer (score 1):

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "shoesDetails" {


    let indexPath = self.table.indexPathForSelectedRow()


   let shoesCon:ShoesTableControler = segue.destinationViewController as! ShoesTableControler
    let shoesCategories:RepoSitory = arrofRepository[indexPath!.row]

       shoesCon.object = shoesCategories
         }
    }

 class ShoesTableControler: UIViewController {

var object : RepoSitory?
```

its solve my problem i have my own mistake sorry for posting this question