# How to access variables which located in another class

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to access a var which located in another class(ViewController), but I cannot access answeredCorrectly variable in LastView class. How can I access it and when I call answeredCorrectly like that(marked with 1) is it going to use the default instance of ViewController?

I tried that(LastView.swift)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit



class LastView: ViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var numberLabel: UILabel!

    func assignLabelToCount(){
        numberLabel.text = "\(answeredCorrectly)"
    }

}
```

Whole View Controller

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {



    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerBox: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

       answerBox.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)




    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    var questionShowing = ""
    var answerForControl = 0
    @IBAction func newButton() {
        var question = getQuestion()
        questionShowing = question.0
        answerForControl = question.1
        questionLabel.text = questionShowing
        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: Selector("endGame"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        print()
    }

    func print(){
        println("\(questionShowing) >>>>>> \(answerForControl)")
    }





        var answeredCorrectly = 0


    func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
        var answerInInt = String(stringInterpolationSegment: answerForControl)
        var answer: String? = String(answerInInt)
        if answerBox.text == answer {
            newButton()
            answeredCorrectly++
            answerBox.text = ""
        } else {
        }
    }

    func endGame(){

        println("Count of correct answers: \(answeredCorrectly)")
        answeredCorrectly = 0
        LastView().assignLabelToCount()
        performSegueWithIdentifier("toEnd", sender: nil)
    }

    func getQuestion() -> (String, Int){...}


}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you share data between view controllers and other objects in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734954/how-do-you-share-data-between-view-controllers-and-other-objects-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you could do, if you want to utilize `inheritance`, go ahead and try this kind of structure:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
  //the var you want to access
  var answeredCorrectly: Int = ViewController().answeredCorrectly
  //your other code
  //....
}
```

then, `inherit` the class, since your class `LastView` *inherits* `ViewController`, any class that *inherits* `ViewController` will now have access to `UIViewController`.

**Note**

If you haven't changed the subclass of your `ViewController`, it should be `UIViewController` by default.

let's inherit the class for your `LastView` class:

```
class LastView : ViewController {
  //now your LastView class inherits from ViewController, which also inherits
  //from UIViewController, it's like a big chain of classes
  @IBOutlet weak var numberLabel: UILabel!

  func assignLabelToCount() {
    numberLabel.text = "\(answeredCorrectly)"
  }
}
```

The function just simply assigns your variable `answeredCorrectly`, which is located in `ViewController`.

Comment: When I did what you wrote I got an runtime error. I also added LastView().assignLabelToCount() this on segue function. I got the same error here too.                                                                           numberLabel.text = "\(answeredCorrectly)"                                          //Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: Could you share more of your code, and where you're getting the error? @Encul

Comment: I edited the question and added more code @Justin Rose

Answer (score 0):

declare variable numberLabel as public

Comment: This would only matter if he's got multiple frameworks in his workspace.  By default, the variable is `internal` which means it can be accessed by everything else in the framework...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create instance of that class to access the variable.

Ex:

```
var lastViewInstance: LastView = LastView() // Declare in the class in which you want to access the variable

lastViewInstance.numberLabel.text = "Access from Another class"
```

This is how you can access any variable or outlet!

Comment: I won't down vote because this technically isn't wrong, but it's almost certainly not actually right.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your object into disk by using `NSUserDefaults` and you can use it this way:

Store your object to `NSUserDefaults`:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("YouObjectValue", forKey: "YourKey")
```

After that you can access it anywhere into your project this way:

```
let yourVar: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("YourKey")
```

Hope it will help you.