# How to Pass Data From UICollectionViewCell to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to pass data from `UICollectionViewCell` when I selected to `UITableView` and displayed inside `UITableView` Inside the array

This is a images are for reference :

[image]

[image]

so I output the data to string

```
cell.foodName.text = foodnameout
cell.priceS.text = foodpriceout
cell.foodcounttext.text = foodcountout

println("\(cell.foodName.text):\(cell.foodcounttext.text)")
```

Comment: use singleton class for storing data and use it

Comment: Do you have an example of the work on it ?

Comment: No, don't use a singleton class.  There are ways to pass data between objects without using singletons.  There are many ways.  The sooner novices start learning that, the better.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as too broad.  You give us no information about how the table view cell is related to the collection view cell (how to get from A to B).  It's very, very unclear what you're asking.  Even if you were to clarify it, this question would remain either too broad or a duplicate.  I'm recommending you spend some time going through some pretty basic object-oriented programming tutorials and learn about how objects work.

Comment: @nhgrif can you please explain which are the many ways for that ?

Comment: @PravinTate http://stackoverflow.com/q/29734954/2792531 there's a start.

Comment: This is a duplicate of many other questions like this. Many ways to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)