# Is it ok to use NSUserDefaults to persist and pass data between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I recently came across a [website](http://matteomanferdini.com/how-ios-view-controllers-communicate-with-each-other/) where the blogger recommends not to use *NSUserDefaults* to pass data between viewControllers which is the method I have been using.

This is how I'm using NSUserDefaults to store the user's settings values of an app.

**1**- The first thing I do in my main ViewController is add constant variables for all of my keys to be able to read them globally.

```
 let kOne= "keyOne"
 let kTwo = "keyTwo"
 class ViewController: UIViewController{
     //code...
 }
```

**2**- In *AppDelegate.swift* I initialize all of my key values in the *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions* method.

```
    // set default values for NSUserdefaults keys
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults([ kOne : "0", kTwo:"0" ])
```

**3**- Then in my ViewController I read the values.

```
func keyOneFromDisc()->Double{
   let keyOneValue:String = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(kOne)!
   return Double(keyOneValue)!
}

   // do something with the value...
```

**4**- In a *SettingsViewController* I read and save NSUserDefaults again.

```
    func keyOneFromDisc()->Double{
         let keyOneValue:String = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(kOne)!
        return Double(keyOneValue)!
    }
// more functions...

// save my settings
    @IBAction func saveSettings(sender: AnyObject) {

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(someValueFromAnInputField.text, forKey: kOne)
// more keys
    }
```

**I is this a bad practice?**

**What would be a better way to accomplish what I described above?**

> EDIT: Sorry about the confusion, I forgot to mention that I actually
>   need to persist the data I'm passing around. I do use `prepareForSegue` when passing data around that do not need to be persisted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you share data between view controllers and other objects in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734954/how-do-you-share-data-between-view-controllers-and-other-objects-in-swift).  The core of this question isn't really about `NSUserDefaults`, but rather about how to access the same data through multiple objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NSUSerdefault` for storing less amount of data, like for login purpose or BOOL flag etc. But every time you can't store data for transition of ViewController.

For That Purpose you can use

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

Answer (score 1):

NSUserDefault are used to keep data between app execution. The problem is there is nothing certain about **when** the data will be saved (if i remember correctly).

The way i do it is either through a shared Model object for siblings VCs, or throught relationships & delegation between the VCs when there are parent/sub viewcontrollers.

Comment: `The problem is there is nothing certain about when the data will be saved` -- this isn't actually a problem... but the rest of this answer is mostly correct-ish.

Answer (score -2):

it better to make variables in both of controllers and transfer data in prepareForSegue method. But if this data is one and only for the whole application - you can just store it in AppDelegate. It makes possible reading and saving this data from any place of your app.

Comment: `AppDelegate` is not a dumping ground for all of your everything.  Please stop dumping your global crap into the `AppDelegate` and please stop recommending others do this.  It's *horrendous* and not any better than using `NSUserDefaults` for passing data around.  You need an actual data layer.

Comment: Kolya, if you're asking if I'll write *your* code for you, the answer is no.  If you're asking whether or not I create an appropriate data layer for *my* code, the answer is yes.