# Give Values to Buttons - Swift

Tags: swift, button, view

I was wondering if someone can help me with this. Right now when I click on the button 0 it will automatically take me to the 2nd screen for testing purposes. Now I want to give value to the numbers accordingly and when the number clicked is equals to the number on  my label than it will show the 2nd screen. If not, the Question mark label will blink or change color. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Place this variable above viewDidLoad():

```
var chosenNumber: Int?
```

Attach your buttons to an IBAction like this one and in the storyboard make each of their tags equal to their face value.

```
@IBAction func aNumberButtonWasPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    chosenNumber = sender.tag
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "theSegueIdentifier", sender: nil)
}
```

Pass the number to the following view controller like so and then use that number to populate the label accordingly.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    if let vc = segue.destination as? TheViewControllerYouAreGoingTo {
        vc.theVariableYouWantToSaveYourNumberTo
    }
}
```

If you want to know how to do something differently, just ask.

If you want to really learn swift well, I highly recommend taking this Paul Hegarty Course for FREE. [Paul Hegarty Course](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-9-apps-swift/id1104579961)

The first two lessons specifically will teach you everything you could want to know about proper swift syntax and building a calculator early on. It might seem slightly advanced, but that is why I have watched the course 3 times now. Every 3-6 months since I started learning Swift this has helped refine my skills.

### EDIT

```
let thisString = label.text
let thisInt = Int(thisString)
```

thisInt will be an optional, so at some point you will need to unwrap it. You can use it however you want to and set it to another label like so:

```
anotherLabel.text = "\(thisInt)"
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to populate the label. What I need is to check the value of the label and if the number pressed has the same value than it will take me to the second view.

Comment: Instead of using tags, you could use the actual value of the label. I will edit my answer with that example.

Comment: Yes what i need is that if the button pressed has the same value as the label value than it will take me to the 2nd view.

Comment: Can I add you on Skype or talk to you somewhere since I need to solve this... it's driving me crazy

Comment: I am fine with that, but I am at work for another hour or two. Skype: Sethmr1989

Comment: Yes ok I will wait dw... maybe we can solve it with teamviewer later on. Thanks