# Pass data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

See my `ViewController` first :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UICollectionViewDataSource {


var customCollectionView : UICollectionView!
let myMenu : Menu = {
    let menu = Menu()
    menu.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    menu.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return menu
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupCollectionView()
    view.addSubview(myMenu)
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0" : myMenu]))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[v0(50)]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0" : myMenu]))
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func setupCollectionView(){
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height-50)
    customCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    self.customCollectionView.delegate = self
    self.customCollectionView.dataSource = self
    customCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    customCollectionView.register(FeedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CellID")
    view.addSubview(customCollectionView)

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellID", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

In that `ViewController`, I added a menu set in at bottom and a `CollectionView`.

And in `CollectionViewCell` of `CollectionView` I added a `tableView`.

My question is: how to change data in the tableView when I tapped an option in the menu?

I can't post image directly because I'm a newbie so this is link [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzYa4.png)

In my case, I have one 'ViewController', 'Menu', 'UICollectionViewCell' Class

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734954/how-do-you-share-data-between-view-controllers-and-other-objects-in-swift) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/434/passing-data-between-view-controllers#t=201612192205593320018) from documentation

Comment: In my case, I just have one ViewController

Comment: https://github.com/tarsVEVO/Myproject
here's my project, pleasee check it and help me

Comment: The links I shared APPLY to passing data between 2 classes. They **don't** have to be of type `viewController` for them to work. So passing data from tableview to another viewcontroller is a good application of the links I sent. Having that said, "Tapped an option in the menu" means where exactly? The red bar at the bottom of your image?! What is link Result?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the entire tableView when a user, using tab bar, clicks and goes to another tab—how can you change the tableView? It's really confusing of what you want to do. Your title just says pass data, but pass data between what and what?