# How can I access Data from a sub-entity to the Entity File

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, core-data

I have a `tableView` which contains different members who all have a start amount of money. If the user selects a member, he comes to a `tableView` where all transactions of this user are displayed. I want now to show at the `memberCell` the amount of all transactions plus the start money. But I cannot access the data from the transactions. I also have a label, where the amount of all transactions is shown. So I need to access this data from the `TransactionsViewController` to the `MemberViewController`. My question is: How can I do that?

Core-Data Model:
[image: Core-Data Model]

Comment: This looks like another "how do I pass data between my view controllers" question. In such case it's a duplicate [of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734954/how-do-you-share-data-between-view-controllers-and-other-objects-in-swift). Of course you could solve it by using core data functionality if you only want to involve the member view controller.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson does this also work backwards? I want to pass data from Transactions to Members

Comment: Yes it does. There are examples of this in the link

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I don‘t get it there, could you give me an advice if you understand how to do it?