# Item appends to array in one view controller but not in another

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, viewcontroller

I have a TableView that displays a list of entries in the cells. The entries are stored in an array. The user enters in text for the entries in another view controller (modal), hits "Save", and after `.reloadData()`, the new entry should append to the array and display in the TableView. The array lives in the `HomeController`.

To pinpoint where the problem might be, I've tried appending some text in the `HomeController`, then appending to the same array from the `NotesController`. In the latter, when I print `homeController.entryInput`, I'm expecting `["hello", "goodbye"]`. Instead, I only get `["goodbye"]`.

Also, when I click on "Save" in `NotesController` a second time, I get `["goodbye"]` again instead of `["goodbye", "goodbye"]`. So it looks like the array gets overrided.

I've also tried hard coding items into the array, and they show up fine in the TableView. When I append an item from `NotesController`, it appends to the array but doesn't show on the TableView, and when I add another item from the same ViewController, it overwrites the first item I appended rather than adding it as a new item.

**HomeController:**

```
class HomeController: UIViewController {

    let tableView = UITableView()

    var entryInput: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupTableView()
    }

    func setupTableView() {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        self.entryInput.append("hello")
        print(entryInput)

        tableView.register(HomeCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        let height = view.frame.height
        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: height)

        tableView.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(tableView)
    }

extension HomeController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return entryInput.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! HomeCell
        cell.entryTextLabel.text = entryInput[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

**NotesController:**

```
class NotesController: UIViewController {
    let homeController = HomeController()
    ...
    let saveBtn = UIView().navigationBtn(text: "Save")

    let homeController = HomeController()override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        saveBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(save(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func save(sender: UIButton) {
        homeController.entryInput.append("goodbye")
        homeController.tableView.reloadData()

        print(homeController.entryInput)

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I've looked all around Stack Overflow and other websites about appending to arrays but for some reason can't seem to figure out why I can't append to an array in another class.

Comment: Add log in viewDidLoad of HomeController class and check if it is getting called or not.

Comment: It could be that you have multiple HomeViewController. So when you are appending data to the HomeViewController from NotesController it is a new instance. Is the NotesController the main VC or the modal you're talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have create new ***HomeController*** in ***NotesController*** that doesn't reference to your current ***HomeController***.

```
class NotesController: UIViewController {
    let homeController = HomeController()
}
```

When ***HomeController*** want to open ***NotesController***.
And ***NotesController*** want to communicate back to ***HomeController***.
You should pass ***HomeController*** reference to ***NotesController***.

```
func routeToNotesController() {
    let vc = NotesViewController()
    vc.homeController = self
    let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    present(nc, animated: true)
}
```

---

**Answer your questions.**

1. From the NotesController after save called. You're expecting
   ["hello","goodbye"] but you get ["goodbye"] instead.

   - Because you are instantiate ***HomeController*** in
     ***NotesViewController*** The homeController that you create is not 
     the same ***HomeController*** appear on the screen, It's new so
     homeController and entryInput still empty because viewDidLoad isn't
     call.
2. When you add another item from ***NotesViewController***, You're
   expecting ["goodbye", "goodbye"] but you get ["goodbye"] instead.

   - According the first answer. You create new homeController(that not
     relate to existing one on the screen) inside ***NotesController***
     every time it appear on the screen.

---

Here is the result.

- Left image show ***HomeController***.
- Middle image show ***HomeController*** that open ***InputsController***.
- Right image show ***HomeController*** that updated by ***InputsController***.

> [image] 
>   [image]
>   [image]

---

My implementation.

```
class ListViewController: UITableViewController {
    var entryInput: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "ListViewController"
        tableView.backgroundColor = .white
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(add))
        entryInput.append("hello")
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    @objc func add() {
        let vc = InputViewController()
        vc.listViewController = self
        let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        present(nc, animated: true)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return entryInput.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = entryInput[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

class InputViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var listViewController: ListViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "InputViewController"
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .save, target: self, action: #selector(save))
    }

    @objc func save() {
        listViewController?.entryInput.append("goodbye")
        listViewController?.tableView.reloadData()
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example and detailed answer. I understand why **vc**, although I wasn't clear enough in my statement that by the time **NotesController** appears, it's already been pushed onto a stack of views. When user taps "Add", the first one in the stack is presented modally and embedded in a NavController, user clicks through the VCs until the last one, **NotesController** which is dismissed when user taps "Save". What can I do instead?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the line:

```
let homeController = HomeController()
```

creates a new instance of the class `HomeController` and does not refer to the already existing ViewController. Which means: modifying the array in the new instance of `HomeController` won't affect your main ViewController.

This also leads to the answer of your question about the missing "hello"-element in your array. When you create the object `homeController` it's array does not have any elements.

When `@objc func save(sender: UIButton)` get's called, you append "goodbye" to the empty array.

By `calling dismiss(...)` you are returning to the original version of your `HomeController()` which does not know anything about the other instance you created in `NotesController()`.

To achieve what you are trying to do, I recommend reading more about how to pass data between ViewControllers:

- [How do you share data between view controllers and other objects in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734954/how-do-you-share-data-between-view-controllers-and-other-objects-in-swift)
- https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-pass-data-between-two-view-controllers